# Search for value within a range of values in two separate vectors

Tags: r, range

This is my first time posting to Stack Exchange, my apologies as I'm certain I will make a few mistakes. I am trying to assess false detections in a dataset.

I have one data frame with "true" detections

```
truth=
ID   Start   Stop    SNR
1   213466  213468  10.08
2   32238   32240   10.28
3   218934  218936  12.02
4   222774  222776  11.4
5   68137   68139   10.99
```

And another data frame with a list of times, that represent possible 'real' detections

> possible=
>     ID Times
>
> 1  32239.76
>
> 2  32241.14
>
> 3  68138.72
>
> 4  111233.93
>
> 5  128395.28
>
> 6  146180.31
>
> 7  188433.35
>
> 8  198714.7

I am trying to see if the values in my 'possible' data frame lies between the start and stop values. If so I'd like to create a third column in possible called "between" and a column in the "truth" data frame called "match. For every value from possible that falls between I'd like a 1, otherwise a 0. For all of the rows in "truth" that find a match I'd like a 1, otherwise a 0.

Neither ID, not SNR are important. I'm not looking to match on ID. Instead I wand to run through the data frame entirely. Output should look something like:

> ID Times     Between
>
> 1  32239.76    0
>
> 2  32241.14    1
>
> 3  68138.72    0
>
> 4  111233.93   0
>
> 5  128395.28   0
>
> 6  146180.31   1
>
> 7  188433.35   0
>
> 8  198714.7    0

Alternatively, knowing if any of my 'possible' time values fall within 2 seconds of start or end times would also do the trick (also with 1/0 outputs)

(Thanks for the feedback on the original post)

Thanks in advance for your patience with me as I navigate this system.

Comment: Can you provide an example output. Is the SNR variable irrelevant? Do you want to only compare rows with the same IDs?

Comment: None of your example cases lie between a start or stop. That's not really ideal for testing.

Comment: Something with `findInterval` perhaps? - `findInterval(c(213467,213500,218679,218679.5,100,400000), t(truth[c("Start","Stop")]) ) %% 2` seems to work okay for instance.

Comment: What do you mean about +/-2, appearing in the title but not the question.

Comment: I adjusted the original post to include my ideal output.  The SNR and ID are in the file, but don't need to be used for this part- I do need to leave them in for the future.  The ranges are narrow, so I'm alternatively interested in anything that falls within 2 of either end of the range.  But that might require an alternative thread!  Thank you for the feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can be conceptulised as a rolling join in `data.table`. Take this simplified example:

```
truth
#   id start stop
#1:  1     1    5
#2:  2     7   10
#3:  3    12   15
#4:  4    17   20
#5:  5    22   26

possible
#   id times
#1:  1     3
#2:  2    11
#3:  3    13
#4:  4    28

setDT(truth)
setDT(possible)
melt(truth, measure.vars=c("start","stop"), value.name="times")[
    possible, on="times", roll=TRUE
    ][, .(id=i.id, truthid=id, times, status=factor(variable, labels=c("in","out")))]

#   id truthid times status
#1:  1       1     3     in
#2:  2       2    11    out
#3:  3       3    13     in
#4:  4       5    28    out
```

The source datasets were:

```
truth <- read.table(text="id start stop
1 1 5
2 7 10
3 12 15
4 17 20
5 22 26", header=TRUE)

possible <- read.table(text="id times
1 3
2 11
3 13
4 28", header=TRUE)
```

Comment: Error in rep(x[[i]], length.out = mn) : 
  attempt to replicate an object of type 'closure'

Comment: Any thoughts?  Thank you!

Comment: Well, I can confirm the above example code works just fine with data.table 1.9.6. Try stepping through each part and adapting it to your example. I.e. - confirm the `melt` part works fine first, then the merge/roll part (the second set of `[]`), then the variable selection part (the third set of `[]`). Your error sounds like you are potentially referencing a variable that doesn't exist in the melt part.

Comment: Never mind my error!  This is perfect!  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I'll post a solution that I'm pretty sure works like you want it to in order to get you started. Maybe someone else can post a more efficient answer.

Anyway, first I needed to generate some example data - next time please provide this from your own data set in your post using the function `dput(head(truth, n = 25))` and `dput(head(possible, n = 25))`. I used:

```
#generate random test data
set.seed(7)
truth <- data.frame(c(1:100),
                    c(sample(5:20, size = 100, replace = T)),
                    c(sample(21:50, size = 100, replace = T)))
possible <- data.frame(c(sample(1:15, size = 15, replace = F)))
colnames(possible) <- "Times"
```

After getting sample data to work with; the following solution provides what I believe you are asking for. This should scale directly to your own dataset as it seems to be laid out. Respond below if the comments are unclear.

```
#need the %between% operator
library(data.table)

#initialize vectors - 0 or false by default
truth.match <- c(rep(0, times = nrow(truth)))
possible.between <- c(rep(0, times = nrow(possible)))

#iterate through 'possible' dataframe
for (i in 1:nrow(possible)){
    #get boolean vector to show if any of the 'truth' rows are a 'match'
    match.vec <- apply(truth[, 2:3],
                       MARGIN = 1,
                       FUN = function(x) {possible$Times[i] %between% x})
    #if any are true then update the match and between vectors
    if(any(match.vec)){
        truth.match[match.vec] <- 1 
        possible.between[i] <- 1
    }
}

#i think this should be called anyMatch for clarity
truth$anyMatch <- truth.match

#similarly; betweenAny
possible$betweenAny <- possible.between
```